# Не редактируются файлы на Joomle

Tags: php, joomla

Ситуация такова: есть сайт, сделанный на Joomle. Расположен на isangi.com, от него есть нужные права на изменения.
При попытке изменить код в любом файле, нет никаких ошибок, код сохраняется, однако видимых изменений на странице не наблюдается. Вообще, даже если целиком закомментировать код. Все это делается через встроенный cPanel.

Пример: http://www.isangi.com/bujaflava/index.php/audios/353-uyo-demu-by-m-lee-ft-fizzo-captain

Изменения проводил как в файлах с корнем /www, так и с /public_html.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Видимо, проблема в кэше. Чтобы это проверить, попробуйте добавить в url какую-то переменную, напрмер http://www.isangi.com/bujaflava/index.php/audios/353-uyo-demu-by-m-lee-ft-fizzo-captain&1 если изменения отобразились, то нужно отключить кэш.

Comment: если редактируешь модули, то проверь в шаблоне переопределение, папка /templates/шаблон/html/